# Submitting files from google colab to kaggle

Tags: file, regression, submit, prediction, kaggle

```
prediction=voting_reg.predict(test_prepared)

submission=pd.DataFrame({'Id':test['Id'],'SalePrice':prediction})

file_name='first_pred.csv'

submission.to_csv(file_name,index=False)

print('Saved file:'+file_name)

!kaggle competitions submit House Prices: Advanced Regression Techniques -f first_pred.csv -m
```

Whenever I try to submit it to kaggle I get this error:

> kaggle competitions submit: error: argument -m/--message: expected one argument

How can I submit files from google colab to kaggle?

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide an actual message to go with your submission. Can be empty.

`kaggle competitions submit favorita-grocery-sales-forecasting -f sample_submission_favorita.csv.7z -m "My submission message"`